# Flat ui nav bar not rendering properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

included CSS files:

```
http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/css/flat-ui.css
http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/css/demo.css
http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
```

Code:

```
  <body>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bright Folio</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-01">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#contactModal" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
     </nav>
  </body>
```

I am getting a weird space below and above the Nav Bar

[image]

Comment: Wheres the `CSS`? Just a random guess, could be the `ul` margin. Set it to `margin: 0;`. But without the `CSS` its very hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: Post your full code including the html & css for area below the nav bar. By default `nav-bar` do not have any margin or padding unless you have added some custom styles to it..

Comment: use firebug to find it. must be some margin from the menu or header.

Comment: Posting links to the `CSS` files is not what we are asking for. Try to setup a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) and give us the link.

Comment: My answer any good to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `margin` around the `nav`. Because you have given us links to `CSS` etc I'm not going to look into where it is. But in this demo you can see the margin is the problem.

### CSS:

```
nav {
    margin: 0!important;
}
```

This is something you can use but I wouldn't recommend using `!important`. So you could use this, or go into the `CSS` files and find where `nav` is being set a margin and remove it.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/r6D8x/)

This is how it looks with the margin (without my fix):

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/r6D8x/1/)

Comment: Hi i was able to remove the space below the nav bar but i am still getting a space on the top

Comment: @vini have you set `margin: 0;` for the `body`?